# Implementing greater than and smaller than in cakephp model sql

Tags: sql, cakephp, model, where-clause

I am new to cake and working on database currently. I have a model like below:

```
/**
*
*I am editing a app which is done in version 1.3
* /app/models/get_provider.php
*/

function getListByCategory($gal_category_id,$gal_location_id,$package,$whether_list = false,$limit=999,$order_by = ""){
$conditions = array("GalProvider.status"=>1,"GalProvider.gal_category_id"=>$gal_category_id,"GalProvider.gal_location_id"=>$gal_location_id);
-------
-------
}
```

The `$package` variable is a special one with the below conditions:

```
if $package = 1,starting_package will be between 15000 to 30000
if $package = 2,starting_package will be between 30001 to 45000
if $package = 3,starting_package will be between 45001 to 60000
```

So how I am going to add this `where` conditions in my `$conditions` variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
<?php
function getListByCategory($gal_category_id,$gal_location_id,$package,$whether_list = false,$limit=999,$order_by = "") {
    $conditions = array(
        "GalProvider.status" => 1,
        "GalProvider.gal_category_id" => $gal_category_id,
        "GalProvider.gal_location_id" => $gal_location_id
    );

    switch ($package) {
        case 1:
            $start = 1500;
            $end = 3000;
            break;
        case 2:
            $start = 30001;
            $end = 45000;
            break;
        case 3:
            $start = 45001;
            $end = 60000;
            break;
    }

    $conditions['AND']['starting_package >='] = $start;
    $conditions['AND']['starting_package <='] = $end;
-------
-------
}
```

So you determine the start and end points of your range, then add them to your query, inside an 'and' key to ensure they're both taken into account.

See doco at http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#complex-find-conditions

Comment: I hate switch statements (though I do enjoy String switch statements in PHP), so here's another option, which will also work for adding future packages that follow same format: `$start = 15000 * $package + ($package > 1 ? 1 : 0); $end = 15000*($package+1);`